# Are admin permissions required to install .NET framework on Windows 10 via ClickOnce

Tags: permissions, clickonce, .net-framework-version, prerequisites

If an application, deployed via the ClickOnce installer, is configured in Visual Studio to require a specific .NET Framework version (e.g. 4.6), does the end-user (running Windows 10) require administrator privileges on the PC to install the specified version of the framework?

Answer (score 1):

Framework installs require admin access because you're updating what are considered system level components. There's no way around that of which I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce deployment enables non-administrative users to install and grants only those Code Access Security permissions necessary for the application.

Comment: I'm not talking about the application, but about the framework. If I set, say, .NET 4.6.1 as a "prerequisite", and the user does not have it, will the user be able to install it from the Microsoft website? Or does this necessarily involve Admin rights on the local machine (which many users in an organization will not have).